# histograms and function graphs with java swing

Tags: java, swing, histogram, graphic

Is there any predefined component in Java Swing that allow to draw [histograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aHistogram_example.svg) or [functions graphs](http://www.analyzemath.com/calculus/continuity/continuous_1.gif)?

If there is not. Does anyone know a good open-source library with a license that is not GPL2.0/3.0 ? ( I need any product licensed under MIT/Apache/Eclipse/LGpl licenses).

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/index.html) is a popular Java library with which you can make all kinds of charts, including histograms and function graphs. It's licensed with the LGPL license.

Something that I find a little annoying with JFreeChart is that you have to pay for their [Developer Guide](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/devguide.html), and that you have to pay for each user of that guide separately (i.e. one developer can't legally lend his copy to another developer, unless you buy a more expensive site license). API documentation is available for free though.

Answer (score 3):

For a general purpose graphing library, try out [Batik SVG Toolkit](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) (Apache license). With Batik, you can embed any kind of SVG graphics into your Swing applications, including histograms and function graphcs. For Swing-specific documentation, see ["Batik Swing Components"](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/swing.html).

Drawing histograms and function graphs in SVG is rather trivial. The [histogram example you linked from Wikipedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Histogram_example.svg) for instance is an SVG file and can be viewed with Batik.

Comment: +1 . thanks for the suggestion. Anyway I need to generate graphics from data inside my program. I haven't svg filel to print.

Comment: I know, but with Batik you can also generate SVG files (http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/svg-generator.html) as well as modify them on-the-fly with scripting. Of course I understand Batik is much more general purpose solution that you could be needing here.

Answer (score 1):

JFreechart is the common solution, but on their site they list other options with the licensing details.

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/faq.html#FAQ13